# How to get PyCharm to check PEP8 code style?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm (v 2.7.2) to develop a Django app, but I can't get it to check PEP8 style violations.
I have enabled "PEP8 coding style violation" in the "Inspctions" section of the settings, but PyCharm doesn't highlight the style violations.
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Works for me (every platform).

Comment: It doesn't for me... ie: I separate classes with more than 2 lines and nothing happens

Comment: Fill a bug report, in my experience this feature works just fine. May be your environment is triggering some obscure bug.

Comment: [PEP8 inspection](http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/5059/a0m1.png) needs to be enabled, make sure `Power Save mode` is not enabled in `File` menu, try `File` | `Invalidate Caches` and restart.

Comment: You can try update to the 2.7.3 version or reinstall the 2.7.2. Works fine here with both versions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Which version of Python are you using? If it is Python 3 (maybe specifically Windows 64 bit), there are a couple of bugs logged against that on JetBrains' site:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-8923

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-8077

Comment: That's exactly what happened. I moved to Ubuntu 13.04 a while ago and Pycharm works perfectly fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Mine wasn't showing up due to the color scheme. By default it's marked as "weak warning", so you might have to edit the appearance to make it visible. Editor > Colors & Fonts > General > Errors and Warnings.

Answer (score 8):

OP asks for a way to highlight PEP8 errors on PyCharm,  but there's another way (much clearer in my opinion) to see the violations (extracted from [PyCharm's docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/inspection-tool-window.html)). Open  Code | Inspect Code and friends:

> **Inspection Tool Window**
>
> View | Tool Windows | Inspection:
>
> - You can access the tool window this way only when it is already opened through Code | Inspect Code.
> - After you deactivate the tool window manually by clicking the Close button, the tool window is again available only through Code | Inspect Code.
>   The Inspection tool window displays inspection results on separate tabs

Just tested it on a *PyCharm Community Edition* and it worked like a *charm* (no pun intended).

Answer (score 5):

For me I found that the best way for me was to include pep8 checking as an external script, something along the lines of this:

https://web.archive.org/web/20121206054036/http://blog.saturnlaboratories.co.za/archive/2012/09/10/running-pylint-pycharm

The advantage of doing this is that the errors appear as sort of a todo list the bottom of the frame. This way I don't have to look around the code for errors.

Comment: Broken link. Can you find a cached version?

Comment: Archive.org does have a copy https://web.archive.org/web/20121206054036/http://blog.saturnlaboratories.co.za/archive/2012/09/10/running-pylint-pycharm

Answer (score 1):

Well, I wish I had a better answer, but what helped me was simply the following:

1. switch the interpreter from a remote one to a system one
2. wait until the Pycharm indexing is done
3. switch the interpreter back to the initial/desired one

Comment: I didn't expect this to work honestly, but it did... Thank you! Can anyone explain what is the correlation here?